# How many strands of Myosin Head is in a Myosin filament?

Tags: human-biology

I am doing a research about sacromere in striated muscles, I read a paper (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3963759/
) and it states the follow:

"Rotational symmetry is defined by the number of strands present. Actin filament has two strands and hence has a 2-fold (C2) rotational symmetry; myosin filament has three strands and hence has a 3-fold (C3) rotational symmetry. Helical symmetry is defined by the integral number of sub-units contained in a given number of turns in a single strand. So for example actin filament strands have a 13/6 helix, i.e. thirteen subunits in six turns of a strand, whereas myosin strands have a 9/1 helix, i.e. nine subunits in one turn of its strand."

Now what does it mean by "myosin filament has three strands and hence has a 3-fold (C3) rotational symmetry" ?

How many strands of myosin heads is in myosin filament? I saw visualizations in different papers showing different numbers.